# Python aesthetics in long method call

Tags: python, pep8

I have some code that looks basically like this:

```
class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Base, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def test_echo(self, test_string):
        ''' echo test '''
        response, status_code = self.__agent__.Util.post_v1_util_echo(sessionToken=self.__session__,
                                                                      keyManagerToken=self.__keymngr__,
                                                                      echoInput={"message": test_string}
                                                                      ).result()
        return status_code, response

    def create_datafeed(self):
        ''' create datafeed '''
        response, status_code = self.__agent__.Datafeed.post_v4_datafeed_create(sessionToken=self.__session__,
                                                                                keyManagerToken=self.__keymngr__
                                                                                ).result()
        # return the token
        return status_code, response['id']

    def read_datafeed(self, datafeed_id):
        ''' get datafeed '''
        response, status_code = self.__agent__.Datafeed.get_v4_datafeed_id_read(sessionToken=self.__session__,
                                                                                keyManagerToken=self.__keymngr__,
                                                                                id=datafeed_id
                                                                                ).result()
        return status_code, response

    def send_message(self, threadid, msgFormat, message):
        ''' send message to threadid/stream '''
        # using deprecated v3 message create because of bug in codegen of v4 ( multipart/form-data )
        response, status_code = self.__agentdepr__.Messages.post_v3_stream_sid_message_create(sessionToken=self.__session__,
                                                                                              keyManagerToken=self.__keymngr__,
                                                                                              sid=threadid,
                                                                                              message={"format": msgFormat,
                                                                                              "message": message}
                                                                                              ).result()


  return status_code, response
```

But I think that's pretty ugly ( aesthetically ).
It's also too damned long on the line, technically a PEP8 violation.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to write that in a more aesthetically pleasing way?

The method names are codegen'ed from a swagger file, so I don't want to change that.

Comment: One thing you could do is create aliases int the `__init__` for some of the more frequently used parts like `self.datafeed = self.__agent__.Datafeed`, but that will only get you so far. My suggestion would be to break the lines with `\\`. It is not exactly prohibited: [Line length section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)

Comment: You can end a line on `(` and start the function arguments on the next line, indented, [as described here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out). That will stop everything being piled up on the right.

Answer (score 2):

What about using some local variables? A good rule of thumb is to only have one function call per line.

```
def send_message(self, threadid, msgFormat, message):
    ''' send message to threadid/stream '''
    message_dict = {"format": msgFormat, "message": message}
    kwargs = {'sessionToken': self.__session__,
              'keyManagerToken': self.__keymngr__,
              'sid': threadid,
              'message': message_dict}

    # using deprecated v3 message create because of bug in 
    # codegen of v4 ( multipart/form-data )
    messsages = self.__agentdepr__.Messages
    post = messages.post_v3_stream_sid_message_create(**kwargs)
    response, status_code = post.result()
    return status_code, response
```